# How does a UIView know about an added subview's UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uiview, uiviewcontroller

in the case of say

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
...
[window addSubview:gameController.view];
...
}
```

how does the view of gameController retain association to gameController? I've peaked through all of the Debugger variables and I see no association other than a boolean flag that it belongs to a view controller. so the view is passed along to a view hierarchy (wouldn't necessarily have to be off of window), yet gameController will get events such as shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation . Where is this being kept track of if not as some tucked away reference in the UIView passed out of gameController.view

```
UIView *tmp = gameController.view;
[window addSubview:tmp];
```

Its obvious that gameController knows about tmp, but how does the window know about gameController after that code?

Answer (score 4):

UIViewController is a descendant of UIResponder and is inserted into the responder chain between the view and that view's superview. So calling `nextResponder` on a view managed by a UIViewController will return said instance of UIViewController.

This is how events such as `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` get passed up through the hierarchy of instances of UIResponder. A diagram showing this can be seen in [figure 3.1 in the iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9).